# Evaluating $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{ x+y+1}{ \ln(x^{2}+ 2y^{2})}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this question.
$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{ x+y+1}{ \ln(x^{2}+ 2y^{2})}$$
So I have the limit of both $x$ and $y$ going towards $0$. I'm a bit stuck here. I think I'm supposed to Maclaurin the $\ln$ part by using $\ln(x+1)$ and then use polar coordinates to solve the rest. The answer is supposed to be $0$ but I just get that the limit doesn't exist. It feels like the key to solving this lies in the ln part but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: The limit in the numerator is 1 (which is different from $0$ and $\infty$; the limit in the denominator is $-\infty$; hence the limit of the ratio is $0$.